# Unknown require error in javascript/react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning react js with the help of [scrimba](https://scrimba.com). I created a component called `TodoItem.js` with the following code:

```
import React from "react"

    function TodoItem() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" />
                <p>Placeholder text here</p>    
            </div>
        )
    }
    
    export default TodoItem
```

Whenever I try using it in `App.js` I am getting the error

> Unknown require: ./components/Todoitem (in module /App.js) (/App.js:5)

**App.js:**

```
import React from "react"
import TodoItem from "./components/Todoitem"

function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            <TodoItem />
            <TodoItem />
            <TodoItem />
            <TodoItem />
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

**Index.js**:

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
import App from "./App"

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />, document.getElementById("root")
)
```

What is the error here?

Kindly comment if more information is needed.

Comment: Maybe you have a typo in the filename in import?
import TodoItem from "./components/Todoitem"

Comment: @ПетровКирилл, Ok I got the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply made a mistake in the import:
Wrong: `import TodoItem from "./components/Todoitem"`
Correct: `import TodoItem from "./components/TodoItem"`

Comment: Please don't answer questions where the solution is "Fix the typo". This type of question has no long term value since other people with the same problem are not going to find this by searching. "Typo" is one of the standard Close Vote reasons. Answering this type of question can block the OP from deleting it to remove bloat from StackOverflow. You can delete this answer to remove the possibility of blocking such clean up.

Comment: oh alright my bad. rookie mistake. anyway it says i cannot delete the accepted answer